# What Are Advantages and Disadvantages of SHA-256?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I'm a newbie to Cryptography. I'm learning about SHA-256 hash function now and I wish to have an overall look on it. What are its advantages and disadvantages comparing to other hash functions, like X11, Scrypt,...?

Comment: Advantages and disadvantages are determined by use case. It is not possible to answer this question without knowing what exactly you intend to hash and why. There are [articles out](http://blockgen.net/sha256-vs-scrypt-vs-x11-algorithms/) there that discuss them in the context of cryptocurrencies/proof of work; Is that your use case?

Comment: The chief advantage that SHA-256 has over Scrypt is that it is far more efficient.  The chief disadvantage that SHA-256 compared to Scrypt is that it is far more efficient.

Comment: If *memory* serves me well there are a few more differences, I think you should take above funny comment with a grain of *salt* ;)

Answer (score 9):

All three of the hashes you list serve very different purposes. Asking what their relative advantages and disadvantages ar is like asking about the same about a screwdriver, hammer, and drill.

[SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), and is typically a building block for other cryptographic constructs. In satisfying the requirements of cryptographic hash, it's a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) that is deterministic, fast to compute, resistant to [pre-image and second-preimage attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), and is [collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance).

[scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) is a password-based [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). It's used to turn a low-entropy password into a cryptographic key or verifier with effectively higher entropy by being intentionally slow to compute. It's tunable to require larger amounts of CPU and/or memory as technology advances, making hardware dedicated to computing it en masse expensive.

[X11](https://litecoin.info/X11) from what I can gather is a proof-of-work function for blockchain-based currencies. It appears to be little more than inelegantly mashing of a bunch of unrelated hash functions together in the naïve hope that that will somehow make it ASIC-resistant and more secure. I don't think it's received any analytic attention from cryptographers.